# How to use proxy on a code written in Ruby 1.8?

Tags: ruby, sockets, tcp, proxy, irc

My friend and I are trying to improve a certain ruby program that runs an automated talking bot for IRC. We've managed to tweak some codes from it, but we don't really know how to go about implementing socket communication on TCP via proxy for a pre-existing code written in ruby 1.8. We've googled, but most only refer to Ruby 3.0.

Any help would be appreciated!

The code is:

```
connect(TCPSocket.open(@user.settings("host"), @user.settings("port").to_i(),
      @user.settings("localhost")))
```

and connect is defined as

```
def connect(sock)
@sock=sock
@myprefix= nil
end
```

Comment: So where's your code?

Comment: We can't help you if you don't post your code.